# CreateJS - Can't tween secondary stage

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, createjs

I'm working on a web-app that uses CreateJS. Due to the nature of the app, I am using the API's DOMElements, and as such, if I want to draw anything over those DOMElements I'd have to create a secondary Stage object (which I have). I have the referenced canvas originally positioned offscreen, so I can still access the primary stage, but when I try to call any Tweening on it (to bring it into the screen), it / the canvas doesn't change whatsoever.

It is a different canvas than the one referenced by the primary stage.
Otherwise, I have instantiated but it and the secondary canvas element nearly identically to their respective original counterparts.
I can Tween the primary stage without any problems.
When I do call Tween on the secondary stage, it takes about as long as I specified, and is hitting the call() at the end.
Logging the alpha of the secondary stage before and after the Tween shows that the alpha has changed, and yet the canvas' opacity doesn't change.
Using the Chrome Inspector, I can verify that the canvas does exists and looks/behaves normally when I set the values through the Element tab.

So what I'm guessing is that the canvas isn't actually being controlled at all by the stage element.
My question is: why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Did you verify you call stage.update() on ticks for your second stage ?

Comment: Yup, both are being called. I've worked around the issue by just accessing and Tweening the children. It's not as a broad solution as I would have liked, but it works.